# LineTraceSingleByChannel() not hitting enemies

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I'm currently trying to build a tank game in **Unreal Engine 4.20**. I'm trying to aim my tank turret and barrel onto the player's pointer, by using method **LineTraceSingleByChannel()**. However, when I log my **FHitResult** to the console, I only get the landscape, even when pointing to ennemy tanks, which inherit from Pawn Class.

**Here is my code :**

```
FHitResult HitResult;
auto StartLocation = PlayerCameraManager->GetCameraLocation();
auto EndLocation = StartLocation + (LookDirection * LineTraceRange);
if (GetWorld()->LineTraceSingleByChannel(
    HitResult,
    StartLocation,
    EndLocation,
    ECollisionChannel::ECC_Visibility
)
    )
{
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Hit %s"), *HitResult.Actor->GetName())
    HitLocation = HitResult.Location;
    return true;
}
```

Please help me if you know the answer to my problem!

Comment: I'd probably check the `CollisionChannel` of your enemy tanks, and debug render the line to make sure `LookDirection` is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, do you know how I could trace debug line ?

Comment: You can assign your trace a tag and set `UWorld::DebugDrawTraceTag` to it, or call `DrawDebugLine` and pass your `StartLocation` along with the hit location of your ray.

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't know why but just by adding collision params, every thing went back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

You need to block the Channel: 'Visibility', in the Character(Capsule Component) you want to hit.